# Networked Control

Tags: heat-transfer, airflow, temperature

Considering the air conditioning system for three rooms B, A, and C. Room A is in the center while rooms B and C are on the left and right sides respectively.  What is the coupling value (N) I should take? N=2 or N=3.
[image]

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: It's a small project to do on Matlab. finding a decomposed model, centralized fixed mode, control gains, LMIs, and closed-loop system trajectories